# Can polynomial-sized neural network approximate every (real-valued) function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I know universal approximation theorem says that neural network can approximate every function to arbitrary precision, however it does not bound the size of the neural network. It seems that a more useful theorem would be “what kind of functions can be approximated by polynomial-sized neural networks”. I did some literature search and found Theorem 1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.1141.pdf, which says that every function can be implemented in polynomial time can be **expressed** by a poly-sized neural network. However, it seems that this theorem is restricted to boolean inputs. I'm wondering if it's also true that for every real-valued function that can be evaluated in polynomial time, we can always construct a corresponding neural network of polynomial-size to approximate it (with arbitrary precision)?

Really appreciate if someone can point out some relevant literature for this question.

Comment: One thing: it says you can _approximate_ every function, not _express_ every function.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy thanks for pointing this out! So I think my question is, can poly-sized NN approximate any function to arbitrary precision?

Comment: The universal approximation theorem **does not** say that you can approximate every function to arbitrary precision.

Comment: While UAT covers many functions, there are requirements about continuity of the functions and compactness of the domain and range. In particular, a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ must be bounded, so the function cannot be on the entire real line.